# Set PubSub Subscription Expiration to Never Expire via Terraform

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform

When creating a PubSub subscription manually you have the option of setting the expiration as "Never expire". Example:

[image: expiration set to never expire]

I am attempting to manage my cloud infrastructure through Terraform. The expiration there defaults to 31 days. I have some subscriptions were it is perfectly possible no activity may happen in 31 days and I don't want the subscription to disappear in that case.

Here is an example of the configuring the property [from the Terraform documentation](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/google/r/pubsub_subscription.html):

```
expiration_policy {
  ttl = "300000.5s"
}
```

What it doesn't say is how to set the policy to never expire. Looking at [the GCP API docs](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.subscriptions) it indicates the following structure:

```
"expirationPolicy": {
  object (ExpirationPolicy)
},
```

If I click into `ExpirationPolicy` then I see something of interest:

> If ttl is not set, the associated resource never expires.

This makes me think I should just send an empty expiration policy:

```
expiration_policy {
}
```

But this gives me the following error:

```
Error: Missing required argument

  on main.tf line 39, in resource "google_pubsub_subscription" "mct_bloodrelay_staging":
  39:   expiration_policy {

The argument "ttl" is required, but no definition was found.
```

I'm thinking this is a terraform problem since the docs seem to indicate ttl might be left out and it looks like terraform is requiring it. But before I create a case on the Github project I figured I would post here to see if I am missing something.

Answer (score 4):

Per the [Terraform documentation](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/google/r/pubsub_subscription.html#ttl) for pusub subscription, the `ttl` parameter is required. The only way to get around this is to set it to empy string -

```
  expiration_policy {
    ttl = ""
  }
```

Updated:
full pubsub subscription resource definition example -

```
  resource "google_pubsub_subscription" "test-sub" {
  name  = "test-sub"
  topic = "projects/PROJECT_ID/topics/TOPIC_NAME"
  expiration_policy {
    ttl = ""
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried that and it complained that the `ttl` was not the right format I think it said it must end with a `s` character.

Comment: Did you try with :  expiration_policy {
    ttl = "0s"
  }
}

Comment: what version of terraform and google-provider are you using? can you post the full error message?

Comment: solution works for me